# How to Export power apps solution from one tenant to another tenant in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

How to Export power apps solution from one tenant to another tenant in azure devops ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you refer to PowerApps (canvas App).
usually Canvas APP or Powerapps is mostly been used where dataverse (CRM) is also been used.

We usually create a solution in Dataverse and add canvas app to that solution.
then using solution you can easily transfer/deploy your canvas app.

There are devops Tools provided by Microsoft. [Take a look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tools)

Comment: Hello, I created Powerapps (canvas app) solution in my organization environment so I want to deploy my solution in client environment means its different tenant. I know how to import and export solutions in same tenant but I want to know this same function in Different tenant in azure devops.

Comment: you can do that using devops CI/CD, you just need to connect to client's Env (no matter which tenant) and import your solution which includes your canvas app. Please mark it as solved if this helps.